# Can I create a desktop application with ruby?

Tags: ruby, desktop

I would like to know if its posible to create a desktop application with ruby and the disadvantages,
please can you give me a example? a application to use in windows

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, Sir!

The disadvantages are like there might be some difficulties doing advanced stuff for interfaces but I'm just guessing as I have no experience at all in this field.

Take a look at some solutions you have:

http://shoesrb.com

https://github.com/larskanis/fxruby

https://github.com/maccman/bowline (this one I just found it now and seems interesting, BUT it's not maintained anymore :/)

http://macruby.org (for OS X only)

http://www.rubymotion.com (paid and OS X only)

Other I can think of is using Java Swing with JRuby

Also you might want to take a look at this -> http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules

Comment: I know swing!!!! can I use that to to something with ruby?

Comment: sure! :D with JRuby you can use java packages. Take a look at this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/376-jruby-basics